# Distributing Angular Components with NPM and CSS

Tags: angular

**The tl;dr;**

What is the best way to develop Angular components that will be deployed and consumed with npm in such a way that those who consume those components  can easily override the CSS.

*I do not expect one to write a long reply here; but a pointer to a web site that makes sense of this would be great. I have been trying to make sense of the expected design pattern for some time.*

**More Details:**

I am just learning distributing Angular components via npm. At preset I am using `ng-packagr` to do this. *If you have a suggestion for an alternative please point me in any direction, I may be going down the wrong path here.*

The problem I am running into is I develop my components with a *.scss (structural) and a *.theme.scss (appearance) file but `ng-packagr` seems to bundle these inline.

*It appears the documentation in this is very lax, and that is a shame for the Angular ecosystem.  At this point I am either not getting it, or it appears Google is trying to force us all into the Material CDK*

Comment: webpack is one of the best ways to generate your package many libraries and frameworks already using for distribution have a look here https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

Comment: I am using CLI and webpack, I am just trying to comply with the Angular Package format for component distribution, but it seems to leave out any information on css.

Comment: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library